# Bad inner join performance on one-to-many relationship

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance, join, postgresql-performance

I have a question regarding the postgres planner that I can't wrap my head around. I am trying to get the planner to look up a project ID by its unique key before running the other side of the query joining permitted users.

#### The Issue

There is a significant performance difference between these two queries. I would like to make the inner join to perform better than it currently does, preferably without changing the schema.

##### Subquery

This query is fast, but it is pretty ugly and would require major refactoring in code.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM users
  INNER JOIN permissions ON permissions.user_id = users.id
WHERE
  permissions.project_id = (SELECT id FROM projects WHERE key = 'test')
```

##### Inner Join

This is nice, but super slow. For some reason, the planner uses a hashed or nested join between projects (one row) and the permissions (many rows) instead of running them synchronously - in a more efficient matter.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM users
  INNER JOIN permissions ON permissions.user_id = users.id
  INNER JOIN projects ON projects.id = permissions.project_id
WHERE
  projects.key = 'test'
```

Why is this so slow? Is there a way I can make the planner find the project before finding its users instead of running them both simultaneously in the inner join?

#### Live Example

See the setup and performance here: [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MKPGy6D_)

I have the following tables and indexes (stripped down for the example):

```
# \d users;
 Column    | Type | Nullable 
-----------+------+----------
 id        | int8 | not null 
 name      | text | not null 
Indexes:
"id_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

# \d projects;
 Column    | Type | Nullable 
-----------+------+----------
 id        | int8 | not null 
 key       | text | not null
 name      | text | not null 
Indexes:
"id_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"key_unique" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (key)

# \d permissions;
 Column     | Type | Nullable 
------------+------+----------
 id         | int8 | not null 
 user_id    | int8 | not null 
 project_id | int8 | not null 
Indexes:
"id_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"user_id_fk" btree (user_id)
"project_id_fk" btree (project_id)
"user_id_project_id_idx" btree (user_id, project_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
"fk_user" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
"fk_project" FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES projects (id)
```

#### Update

Changing the index order on the permission table and only selecting necessary columns does speed up the example above, but I may have oversimplified the queries for the example.

In the real-world problem, there is a recursive permissions hierarchy that still has way worse performance when using project key for lookup instead of project ID. See the [updated Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NiCA2eY_).

I would like to understand if there is a way for the optimizer to know that running one part of the query before the other would be faster than doing it in parallel.

Comment: Change the index on permission from (user_id, project_id) to (project_id, user_id). Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/Gg_ar5SW

Answer (score 1):

Select just the columns you need, not `*`.  Do you really need the primary key column from "permissions"?  Doing this, combined, with Andrea's suggestion and a VACUUM, will allow a much faster index-only scan, see https://dbfiddle.uk/ddyTvGts

Comment: Thank you, this does speed up the query above, but I may have oversimplified the queries for the example. There is a recursive permission scheme that still has way worse performance when using project key instead of project id. See [the updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NiCA2eY_).